# Dynamic Google Charts Tool using knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, google-visualization

I'm toying around with setting up a dynamic chart generation tool using Google Charts, Knockout and jQuery.cookie.js.  I have Knockout set to customize supporting copy on the chart, but I'm not sure how to go about updating google charts.

Any help would be much appreciated.  See below for my JSBin

http://jsbin.com/timatuku/26/edit

Answer (score 0):

some untested thoughts...
1) make the initial data array observable and perhaps even the chart object
2) calling a function in your subscribes and passing in the new value along with the index of the array
3) redraw the chart in the function

```
var self = this;
this.chartData = ko.observableArray([..my default data...]);

this.myFunction = function(val, index) {

    self.chartData()[index][2] = val;

    //redraw chart
};
```

It's not the most elegant and you would have to rethink how you initialize the map but something like this could work.

Answer (score 0):

Another untested thought is to create a custom binding for your chart and make the data observable. I have done something similar with maps. I apologize if this is way off. Just a thought.

```
<div class="col--chart" id="donutchart_col1" data-bind="donutchart:chart1Data"></div>

function ViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.myChart = new ko.observable() 
   self.chart1Data = ko.observableArray();
}

ko.bindingHandlers.donutchart = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var chartData = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var theChart = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.myChart);

            theChart = new google.visualization.pieChart(element);
            viewModel.myChart(theChart);
        }
    }
```